# lead function in sql not working as expected

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am using the following query to identify the newEndDate

[image]

But, the result i get is

[image]

Why am i not getting newEnddate for the last row ? please help

Comment: May be you should use a LAG instead of a LEAD?

Comment: For last row, there is no next row, that `lead` could take value from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use same column in `lead()` in last parameter :

```
lead(se.status_startdt, 1, se.status_startdt) over (partition by se.invoice_number order by se.status_startdt)
```

As per sample data this seems to be use of `coalesce()` :

```
coalesce(se.status_enddt, se.status_startdt)
```